# How to prevent XBAP Browser application from being closed in a web browser

Tags: wpf, clickonce, caliburn.micro, xbap

We are developing a WPF application with a XBAP part running in a web browser, both using Caliburn.Micro framework.

There are no problems with implementation and deployment except that there is a requirement the application should not allow user to close it when instantly when some data was modified on the active window and user did not press save.

In the desktop application it is just easy as overriding Caliburn's CanClose method which itself is a part of Window.Closing callback. This callback is executed and CancelEventArgs.Cancel can be set if necessary.

In the XBAP application, Application.Current.MainWindow is a RootBrowserWindow and when it's Closing and Closed events are subscribed, these never get called even if callback is a static method (I'm modifying Caliburn.Micro code here for testing).

My question is how to prevent WPF XBAP browser application running in Internet Explorer from closing when user tries to close the tab or a whole browser window? Application trust is not an issue as we can (and will) ask clients to give full trust for the app.

Comment: Do you mean XBAP browser app? ClickOnce apps are desktop apps...

Comment: @DeanK. Yes he does, or he wouldn't be dealing with explorer and these issues :)

Comment: Sorry surely I meant XBAP browser app.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to my knowledge, you can't, IExplorer restrictions. You are not even allowed to check if your window is minimized and even certain key combos isn't allowed in XBAP applications. Fulltrust or not, IE issue :(

I thinkered with the same issue as you about 3-4 years ago, + some keybindings, did alot of interop stuff, to no avail from what I can remember.

Cheers

Stian

Comment: I was thinking about using JavaScript and opening XBAP in another tab while keeping the "guard" tab open and listening to window.onbeforeunload (if possible). The goal for XBAP app to access IE guard tab's IHTMLDocument seems unreachable without a hell lot of interop as you mentioned.

Comment: @too advice from a XBAP, WPF and SL veteran. Scrap it all together(XBAP)! Certain third party vendors have stopped supporting it. Even though I love WPF and SL, I wouldn't create a XBAP application voluntarily. There are better crossplatform solutions out there. Uhhh just the word PresentationHost.exe gives me nightmares ;) Old failed tech, ActiveX 2.0 :/. And for your question regarding interop, even here you are blocked on so many areas.

Comment: I will use XBAP to deploy a windows app without installing for user convenience in addition to our main desktop app (I've been through XBAP publishing versioning issues and it indeed is a nightmare to make it work and update automatically). What cross-platform solutions you have in mind? We only really need to support Windows.

Comment: @too hehe tell me about it! :) Been working alot with LOB applications which both has it's standard WPF version and XBAP version. Well it all dependes on what you application is going to do? How big it is? For web page stuff, html5 and js no doubt. For Desktop you can still keep on rocking WPF =) Well just my observations, and experience.

Comment: It's a pretty complex application with multiple tabs each having multiple views connected to each other and presenting up to 2 most recent views top-bottom simultaneously. It has message-based updating after changes and all with async WCF queries. One important requirement which would render web too difficult to implement is rich document editing (Images, vectors, formulas). I guess I will struggle with explaining people using XBAP not to close their browser or their data will be gone :) Or think for them and save periodically so after restart "resume editing" dialog can be shown.